# Why does Visual Studio Code randomly lose Flutter class imports?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code randomly gives an error that a class is missing in my code. The class is first imported successfully from the class file into the code. But when I close the file importing it and reopen it, it loses the reference of that imported file and says that the referenced class file could not be found, although it found it before.

I'm creating a widget `PersonalActionPlanBox` that needs to import the widget `PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox` from file `PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox.dart`. I have already tried to find an answer by Googling and here on Stackoverflow but did not find a clear solution. I have tried importing the widget with both formats like `package:...` and the relative `../…`. But none work.

The widget importing the `PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox` giving the reference error:

```
import '../PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox.dart';

class PersonalActionPlanBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final PersonalActionPlan actionPlan;
  final UserModel user;

  PersonalActionPlanBox({this.actionPlan, this.user});

  @override
  PersonalActionPlanBoxState createState() => PersonalActionPlanBoxState();
}

class PersonalActionPlanBoxState extends State<PersonalActionPlanBox> {

...

  List<Widget> buildRowPreviewBoxes() {
    return widget.actionPlan.rows.map((row) {
      return new PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox (
        actionPlanRow: row,
        deleteRowCallback: deleteRowEvent,
        refreshFollowUpDateCallback: refreshFollowUpDate,
        saveActionPlanCallback: saveActionPlan
          );
    }).toList();
  }


... 

}
```

The imported widget `PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox`:

```
class PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox extends StatefulWidget {

  final PersonalActionPlanRow actionPlanRow;
  final DeleteRowEvent deleteRowCallback;
  final RefreshFollowUpDateCallback refreshFollowUpDateCallback;
  final SaveActionPlanCallback saveActionPlanCallback;

  PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox({this.actionPlanRow, this.deleteRowCallback, this.refreshFollowUpDateCallback, this.saveActionPlanCallback});

  @override
  PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBoxState createState() => PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBoxState();
}

class PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBoxState extends 

State<PersonalActionPlanRowPreviewBox> {

...

}
```

I expect Visual Studio Code to not randomly lose the import/reference to `PersonalActionPlanPreviewBox.dart`.

Comment: This has also happened to me recently but I had assumed it was because I had moved my project from one machine onto another. I just run 'flutter packages get',  I've only needed to do this each time I've moved the project.

Comment: I tried running "flutter packages get" but didn't work. Cleaning the project before that didn't help either.